# NFC support in Android via SL4A

Tags: java, android, python, jruby, nfc

I am looking to working with my NFC cards using my Galaxy Nexus. I've been able to read them via 3rd party apps and I'm quite fluent in working with external APIs and Python and was so seeing if there is a way to access android.NFC from SL4A (so I can use python and get raw info). Basically it would be very much appreciated if someone knew how to easily access android.NFC library (wishing there was jython support :/)

Thanks!

**I've found that you can directly call the API via JRuby** [here.](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/FAQ#Is_this_a_complete_API_bridge,_or_are_there_restrictions?)

**I believe this would this allow one to access android.nfc directly??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with NFC in my day to day job, sorry but SL4A does *not* support NFC at all. I would love someone to rig this up but I just don't have time.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way we could implement it via the use of Jython interpreter?

Comment: Maybe. But this would be harder than just coding the interface for SL4A yourself.